# SQLAlchemy best way to filter a table based on values from another table

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I apologize in advance if my question is banal: I am a total beginner of SQL.

I want to create a simple database, with two tables: `Students` and `Answers`.
Basically, each student will answer three question (possible answers are `True` or `False` for each question), and his answers will be stored in `Answers` table.
`Students` can have two "experience" levels: "Undergraduate" and "Graduate".
What is the best way to obtain all `Answers` that were given by `Students` with "Graduate" experience level?

This is how I define SQLAlchemy classes for entries in `Students` and `Answers` tables:

```py
import random

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Date, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship


db_uri = "sqlite:///simple_answers.db"
db_engine = create_engine(db_uri)
db_connect = db_engine.connect()

Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=db_engine)
db_session = Session()


Base = declarative_base()    


class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Students"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    experience = Column(String, nullable=False)

class Answer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Answers"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    student_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Students.id"), nullable=False)
    answer = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)


Base.metadata.create_all(db_connect)
```

Then, I insert some random entries in the database:

```py
categories_experience = ["Undergraduate", "Graduate"]
categories_answer = [True, False]

n_students = 20
n_answers_by_each_student = 3
random.seed(1)
for _ in range(n_students):
    student = Student(experience=random.choice(categories_experience))
    db_session.add(student)
    db_session.commit()
    
    answers = [Answer(student_id=student.id, answer=random.choice(categories_answer))
               for _ in range(n_answers_by_each_student)]
    db_session.add_all(answers)
    db_session.commit()
```

Then, I obtain `Student.id` of all "Graduate" students:

```py
ids_graduates = db_session.query(Student.id).filter(Student.experience == "Graduate").all()
ids_graduates = [result.id for result in ids_graduates]
```

And finally, I select `Answers` from "Graduate" `Students` using `.in_` operator:

```py
answers_graduates = db_session.query(Answer).filter(Answer.student_id.in_(ids_graduates)).all()
```

I manually checked the answers, and they are right. But, since I am a total beginner of SQL, I suspect that there is some better way to achieve the same result.

Is there such an objectively "best" way (more Pythonic, more efficient...)? I would like to achieve my result with SQLAlchemy, possibly using the ORM interface.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I asked the question, I was in a hurry.
Since then, I have had the time to study [SQLAlchemy ORM documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html).
There are two recommended ways to filter tables based on values from another table.

The first way is actually very similar to what I had originally tried:

```py
query_graduates = (
    db_session
    .query(User.id)
    .filter(User.experience == "Graduate")
)
query_answers_graduates = (
    db_session
    .query(Answer)
    .filter(Answer.user_id.in_(query_graduates))
)
answers_graduates = query_answers_graduates.all()
```

It uses `.in_` operator, which accepts as argument either a list of objects, or another query.

The second way uses `.join` method:

```py
query_answers_graduates = (
    db_session
    .query(Answer)
    .join(User)
    .filter(User.experience == "Graduate")
)
```

The second approach is more concise. I timed both solutions, and the second approach, which uses `.join`, is slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning SQL but I am confused if you want to do this particular step in Python or SQL. If SQL, something like this could work:

```
select * from Students s 
inner join Answers a on s.id = a.student_id
where s.experience = "Graduate";
```

Updated code

I have never used SQLAlchemy before but something similar to this may work...

```
sql = """select s.Id, a.answer from Students s 
inner join Answers a on s.id = a.student_id
where s.experience = "Graduate";"""

with db_session as con:
    rows = con.execute(sql)

    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I would like to do that in SQLAlchemy, so in Python.
Could you please explain how to do that in SQLAlchemy, possibly using its ORM interface?

Comment: I just updated the code.  Something like that might work.  You may need to adjust it a bit.  Also updated so you are pulling specific columns instead of Select *

Comment: Yeah, it works! I tried it. The solution is `answers_graduates = db_engine.execute(sql).fetchall()`, if you want to update the answer for other users. `answers_graduates` is a list of tuples, each tuple containing `Student.id` and `Answer.answer` of "Graduate" students. No need to use the `with` statement or to print rows.